# I can't make an object of this class from another class

Tags: java, user-interface, jdbc

I'm trying to open this gui from an action listener in another class but for whatever reason it's not doing it, any and all help appreciated.

```
    package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import database.DBConnection;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class OrderExample {
    static JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTable table= new JTable();
        table.setBounds(428, 445, 396, -328);

        Object[] columns = {"Product Id", "Product Name", "Description", "Price"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);
        table.setModel(model);


        table.setBackground(Color.white);
        table.setForeground(Color.black);
        Font font = new Font("", 1, 22);
        table.setRowHeight(30);

        JTextField prodId = new JTextField();
        JTextField prodName = new JTextField();
        JTextField prodPrice = new JTextField();

        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
        JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");

        prodId.setBounds(20, 56, 230, 38);
        prodName.setBounds(20, 129, 230, 38);
        prodPrice.setBounds(21, 201, 229, 39);

        btnAdd.setBounds(20, 451, 100, 38);
        btnDelete.setBounds(150, 451, 100, 38);
        btnExit.setBounds(20, 511, 100, 39);

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        pane.setBounds(281, 32, 440, 518);

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);

        frame.getContentPane().add(prodId);
        frame.getContentPane().add(prodName);
        frame.getContentPane().add(prodPrice);

        frame.getContentPane().add(btnAdd);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnDelete);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnExit);

        JLabel lblAddId = new JLabel("Product ID");
        lblAddId.setBounds(20, 32, 79, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblAddId);

        JLabel lblProduct = new JLabel("Product Name");
        lblProduct.setBounds(20, 105, 100, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblProduct);

        JLabel lblProductPrice = new JLabel("Product Price");
        lblProductPrice.setBounds(20, 178, 90, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblProductPrice);

        JButton btnListProducts = new JButton("List Products");
        btnListProducts.setBounds(150, 511, 100, 39);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnListProducts);

        JTextArea description = new JTextArea();
        description.setBounds(20, 276, 230, 164);
        frame.getContentPane().add(description);

        JLabel lblDescription = new JLabel("Description");
        lblDescription.setBounds(20, 251, 116, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblDescription);

        Object[] row = new Object[4];

        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                row[0] = prodId.getText();
                row[1] = prodName.getText();
                row[2] = description.getText();
                row[3] = prodPrice.getText();

                model.addRow(row);
                try{
                Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into stock(sname, description, quantity , price) values(?,?,20,?);");
                ps.setString(1,  prodName.getText());
                ps.setString(2,  description.getText());
                ps.setDouble(3, Double.parseDouble( prodPrice.getText()));
                ps.executeUpdate();
                }
                catch(SQLException sqle){
                    sqle.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int i = table.getSelectedRow();
                if(i >= 0){
                    model.removeRow(i);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print("Delete ");


                }
            }

        });

        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                int i = table.getSelectedRow();
                prodId.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 0). toString());
                prodName.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
                prodPrice.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
                description.setText(model.getValueAt(i,  2).toString());
            }
        });

        btnListProducts.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                int i = table.getSelectedRow();
                try{
                Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs;
                if(prodId.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                    rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from stock;");

                else
                    rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from stock where stockID = " + prodId.getText() + ";");

                while(rs.next()){
                    row[0] = rs.getInt("stockID");
                    row[1] = rs.getString("sname");
                    row[2] = rs.getString("description");
                    row[3] = rs.getDouble("price");

                    model.addRow(row);
                }

                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                frame.dispose();

            }
        });
        frame.setSize(771, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is the actionlistener code

```
btnStock.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                OrderExample window = new OrderExample();
            }
        });
```

I've tried to set window to visible but it just gives me an error.

Comment: `but it just gives me an error` - Which error? Please, post the complete stack trace and highlight the line where the error occurs.

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: The default constructor of `OrderExample` does absolutely nothing . How would you expect that calling it would display a window ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `OrderExample`has all of its functionality in its (static) `main` method which is never been called by your `Actionlistener` implementation.

You could simply add the call to `OrderExample.main` to your  `Actionlistener` implementation, but you should better first move the content of `main` to a *non static* method (e.g.: `init`) and call that.

Comment: thank you, it worked, I still have alot to learn! thanks again!